# gdb view structure values in core dump

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I'm having a problem analyzing core dump with gdb. I'm not able to view the contents of any structure in my C code.
When I use:

```
print myStruct->val
```

I get

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x2031b860
```

Or

```
print *myStruct
```

I get the same error.

This happens when I try to print content from every other structure in the code.
But when I try to print a local variable which is in a function, it prints ok.

The sequence of commands executed was:

```
gdb ./myApp ./core
(gdb)bt
.
.
.
#25 0x0868b276 in ikev2_check_icv (ike_sa=0x2031b860, packet=0x2031a950) at ikev2_payload.c:460
.
.
(gdb) frame 25
(gdb) print ike_sa
$1 = (struct ikev2_sa *) 0x2031b860
(gdb) print *ike_sa
Cannot access memory at address 0x2031b860
(gdb)
```

So my question is, does core dump catch memory blocks allocated with malloc? Not just stack frame memory, as it seems from this example.

I'm running this on Linux 2.6.32.45-0.3-xen x86_64

Comment: The fact that you cannot access the memory may be the cause for the core dump. Use the stack trace to see where the pointer to structure comes from. Or use Valgrind to track uninitialised data.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not the case. The core dump is because of another issue. I know where the crash happens, this is just for competence build up in using gdb. As I said, I'm not able to see the content of other structures in the code. It's a big code, but I'm pretty sure that the struct in this example got allocated and initialized properly.

Comment: malloc'ed memory ought to be in the core dump, if the corefile ulimit didn't cause the core dump to be truncated before the data for that part of the heap was dumped. Run `info files` in gdb and see if the core dump file mappings have an address range that includes 0x2031b860.

Comment: you're right Mark, 
(gdb) print ike_sa
$1 = (struct ikev2_sa *) 0x20331880
(gdb) info files
0x20000000 - 0x20000000 is load4
As for the other struct I can't see.
(gdb) print packet
$3 = (rc_vchar_t *) 0x20329ec0
Also falls in this range.
Does this mean that these structures were not allocated properly?

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, does core dump catch memory blocks allocated with malloc? Not just stack frame memory, as it seems from this example.

That is correct.

The symptoms you observe usually indicate that your `core` is truncated.

That can happen when your `ulimit -c` is too low, or when you run out of disk space writing it.

Another possibility is that your `core` got damaged in transfer if you e.g. FTP'd it over from one machine to another for analysis.

Comment: hi, I didn't ftp the file, ulimit -c shows, unlimited...and I have 53G available space on my disk. Could there be another reason?